# How to filter one JSON based on another JSON in Python?

Tags: python, json, pandas

Im trying to write a Python class that takes a json request and a json array, and then filters the array based on the data in the request. Here is the basic folder structure for the project:

```
my_input/
 /request.json
 /array.json

my_python/
 /class.py
```

request.json has the data "place: 1" and "trait: 3", and is of the following form:

```
{
    "metadata": {
        "id": "request",
    },
    "data": {
        "place": [
            "1"
        ],
        "trait": [
            "3"
        ]
    }
}
```

array.json has 2 sub-arrays, *locationArray* and *measurementArray*; in locationArray, we see that place 1 is associated with plots 2 and 3:

```
{  "data":{
    "measurementArray": {
      "headers": ["plot","trait","value"],
      "data": [
        [1, 3, 2.7],
        [2, 2, 1.8],
        [3, 3, 3.6]
       ], 
    "locationArray": {
      "headers": ["place","plot"],
      "data": [
        [1,2],
        [3,4],
        [1,3]
       ], 
       }}}
```

Then we filter plots 2 and 3, where "trait: 3". In this example, it would return just one row from the measurement array, because only one row that was at plot 2 or 3 had trait 3:

```
        [3,3,3.6]
```

How could I write a class to parse the request json and then filter the array in the second JSON? Currently, I only have a blank class.

Thanks so much for considering this question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if it works

```
class my_input:

    def __init__(self,my_request, my_array):
        self.my_request = my_request
        self.my_array = my_array

    def get_places(self):
        return self.my_request['data']['place']

    def get_traits(self):
        return self.my_request['data']['trait']

    def get_associated_plots(self,places):
        associated_plots = []
        place_st = set(places)
        for current_data in self.my_array['data']['measurementArray']['locationArray']['data']:
            if str(current_data[0]) in place_st:
                associated_plots.append(current_data[1])
        return associated_plots

    def get_rows(self,associated_plots,traits):
        triats_st = set(traits)
        associated_plots_st = set(associated_plots)

        for current_data in self.my_array['data']['measurementArray']['data']:
            rows = []
            if current_data[0] in associated_plots_st and str(current_data[1]) in triats_st:
                rows.append(current_data)
        return rows
```